# how to get react function to update state with user input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have written a function in react that, through a rendered submit form, takes a user's input, uses it to query an api and updates p tag content in the form. This is the following code:

```
var textfield = ""
function Form (){
        const [ name, getNFT ] = useState("")
        let postName = (e) =>{
            let output
            async function getInfo(e) {
                e.preventDefault()
                try {
                    const resp = await axios.post("/hey_honey", {
                        name
                    })
                    console.log(resp.data)
                    output = resp.data
                    return output
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error(error)
                }
            }
    
        getInfo(e).then(output =>{console.log("output is outside of function scope", output)
        })
        textfield = output
        return textfield 
    }

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <form onSubmit={postName}>
                <input type="text" value={name} onChange={(e) => getNFT(e.target.value)}/>
                <button type="submit" >Get Collection's Gallery</button>
                <p>{textfield}</p>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I have successfully gotten the JSON string that I wanted. The problem is I seemingly have no way of updating the rendered form because it is either outside of postName's function scope or anything modified by postName even if instantiated outside of form cannot actually change the states.

At one point I thought that this was most likely because this is a more appropriate instance of using a class, I however can't use useState and therefore would have no way of storing the content written out in the submit form. What am I missing here?"
(**Edit:** after some research there are ways I can do this with a class. I technically don't need to utilize useState for a form but rather I could use setState and simply instantiate setState as the empty string.
It would look something like this, and say for the sake of things we just have a function that simply returns the input as opposed to the async function:

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: '', textfield: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    this.setState({textfield: event.target.value})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        <p>{this.state.textfield}</p>
      </form>
      
    );
  }
}
```

However we still run into the issue of updating the form itself.)

**Edit**
Is this a specific issue with forms elements? When someone is posting a comment on a blog is there a different component entirely that I should be using? I was drawn to forms because they take user input and then give you something that you can manipulate but is it maybe that they are immutable once you set them up?

At the time of writing this I am beginning to consider that this is when I should export a stored value, say textfield in my case, and just pass it into an entirely new component. Will update.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is I seemingly have no way of updating the rendered form because it is either outside of postName's function scope or anything modified by postName even if instantiated outside of form cannot actually change the states.

When it comes to React, at the end of the day, if you want to make it re-render you need to update *React state*. What you're doing here with `textfield` is updating a JS variable, but React doesn't have a way of knowing that that variable is different, so it won't know to re-render.

Notice what you're doing with your `input`. Because you've set `value`, it's a "controlled input" and therefore the only reason you can see the text you type is because you're updating React state and triggering a re-render with every key press.

You can do the same thing with the result of your network request. Once the request finishes, you can update a piece of state, which will trigger the re-render. Note that if you don't use that state (e.g. by rendering out some of it) you won't be able to tell that React has re-rendered just from looking at it the browser.

Here's a minimally different example that makes a network request based on your form input and renders the result. (The variable names don't make a ton of sense for this API, just wanted to keep the diff small).

```js
function Form() {
  const [name, getNFT] = useState("");
  const [jokes, setJokes] = useState([]);

  let postName = (e) => {
    let output;
    async function getInfo(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      try {
        // swapped this out to a free public API so we could see a result
        const resp = await axios.get(`https://icanhazdadjoke.com/search?term=${name}`, {
          headers: {
            // you need to tell this API you want the results as JSON, instead of HTML (the default)
            'Accept': 'application/json'
          }
        });
        console.log(resp.data);
        output = resp.data;
        return output;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }

    getInfo(e).then((output) => {
      console.log("output is outside of function scope", output);

      // this is the big change!
      setJokes(output.results);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={postName}>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={name}
          onChange={(e) => getNFT(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button type="submit">Get Collection's Gallery</button>
        <p>{jokes[0]?.joke}</p>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And here's a version that does the same thing but cleans it up a little bit, just to compare:

```js
// this is a pure js function - no react! It just makes the request and returns the result
async function searchJokes(jokeTerm) {
  try {
    // swapped this out so we could see a result
    const jokesResponse = await axios.get(
      `https://icanhazdadjoke.com/search?term=${jokeTerm}`,
      {
        headers: {
          // you need to tell this API you want the results as JSON, instead of HTML (the default)
          Accept: "application/json"
        }
      }
    );

    console.log("jokes response", jokesResponse);
    return jokesResponse.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

function Form() {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
  const [jokes, setJokes] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form
        onSubmit={async (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();

          // whereas the pure js function can just return its request normally, inside here we need
          // to take the result and stick it in React state.
          const jokesData = await searchJokes(searchTerm);
          setJokes(jokesData.results);
        }}
      >
        <input
          type="text"
          value={searchTerm}
          onChange={(e) => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button type="submit">Search Jokes</button>
        <p>{jokes[0]?.joke}</p>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

([Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-dubinsky-ql8bu9?file=/src/App.js:68-1438)). To be clear, the above is definitely not perfect!

---

```js
        getInfo(e).then(output =>{console.log("output is outside of function scope", output)
        })
        textfield = output
        return textfield
```

Setting aside React, one thing to remember is that the code inside the function inside `then` will run when `getInfo(e)` is done fetching its information from the internet, but the lines after run right away without waiting, because the `getInfo` call returns a `Promise`. In JS, async logic like that is non-blocking! You can see above how you use `await` to avoid needing a `then` and the nesting. (But, it's worth remembering that `async/await` is just fancy syntax for Promises and `.then`, so anything you can do with one you can do with the other).

Also, because of function scoping, you won't be able to access `output` outside of the `then` function. You'd have to do that variable assignment inside that function, or use async await to flatten things a bit.

> At one point I thought that this was most likely because this is a more appropriate instance of using a class, I however can't use useState and therefore would have no way of storing the content written out in the submit form. What am I missing here?

In React, it used to be that you needed classes for more complex components, like ones with state, and could only use functions for presentational components. But ever since they introduced hooks, class components and functional components can do the same things in different ways, so what you're doing here is fine! I would stick with function components like you've got while you're learning.

Outside of React, classes *are* a good option when dealing with state (though you can also do equivalent things with nested functions). But you'd still need some way to map updates to your vanilla JS class state to React state. To start, I would focus mostly on storing state within React, and as you build bigger apps you can either spend some time learning how to tie them into your own custom classes, or bring in a state management library (Redux is probably the most well known) to handle that for you.